# Overflowing a register

Tags: assembly

```
mov al,0ffh
add al,5
```

My question is how can I know what will be the value of al after the add line with using the debugger?
And where is the reminder?

Just for the record, the value of al after those 2 lines is 0FEh

**EDIT** the value is 0x04h

Comment: ...huh. I'd really have expected it to be 0x04. I think overflow is well-defined. You sure you're reading it right?

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right.

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger and learn the basics of binary arithmetics. `-1 + 5 = 4`.

Comment: I used the debugger correctly but the code was diffrent then the one that I showed in here, my bad I'm sorry. Anyway so there is no reminder?

Comment: 0xff + 0x05 = 0x104 with the overflow (0x100) thrown away because you're storing into an 8-bit quantity. Therefore `al` will have 0x4 at the end.

Comment: How do you know what's the last (decimal) digit of 9+4? Hint: use a pocket calculator (or paper and pen) for too large values to calculate in your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is the reminder

Not sure what you mean by reminder, but there's a *carry* flag (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791991/about-assembly-cfcarry-and-ofoverflow-flag)).

You can check whether a carry occurred e.g. with the `JC` and `JNC` instructions:

```
MOV AL,0FFh
ADD AL,5
JC there_was_carry  ; <-- this jump will be taken

MOV AL,0F0h
ADD AL,5
JC there_was_carry  ; <-- this jump will NOT be taken
```