# Assembly: FE + FB

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

What will the carry flag (CF), the overflow flag (OF), the sign flag (SF) and the zero flag (ZF) be set to if the following arithmetic is done in an 8-bit register?

`0xFE + 0xFB`

1. CF=1, OF=0, SF=1, ZF=0
2. CF=1, OF=1, SF=0, ZF=0
3. CF=1, OF=0, SF=1, ZF=1
4. CF=1, OF=1, SF=1, ZF=0
5. None of the above.

Thanks

Exercise question from William Stallings - Computer organization and architecture.

Comment: Is there a particular flag you have trouble with?

Comment: What happened when you tried it yourself?  Use a debugger to single-step over `add al, 0xFE` and look at flags.

Comment: I think the mentioned "following arithmetic" is missing...

Comment: @memo: it's in the title.  Agreed it should be in the question, but that edit doesn't make this a good question.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes and others. Will close the question

Answer (score 0):

`CF = 1` because there is an overflow (the unsigned result is 0x1F9 which does not fit in 8 bits)

`OF = 0` because we add 2 negative numbers and the result is also negative

`SF = 1` because the result is negative (bit 7 of the result is set)

`ZF = 0` because the result is not zero

So the answer is 1.
Also see [about assembly CF(Carry) and OF(Overflow) flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791991/about-assembly-cfcarry-and-ofoverflow-flag)